# What does "generator" mean in the master equation?

Tags: open-quantum-systems, master-equation

I seem to read a lot of times that some materials called this $\mathcal{L}$ in the equation(Lindblad master equation) below as the *generator*:
$$
\mathcal{L} \rho=-i[H, \rho]+\sum_{\alpha}\left(V_{\alpha} \rho V_{\alpha}^{\dagger}-\frac{1}{2}\left\{V_{\alpha}^{\dagger} V_{\alpha}, \rho\right\}\right).
$$
I only know the generator in group theory means the minimum component that can span the whole group by the *multiplication* action, but I can't see what does the *generator* there means?

Comment: to add some context to the notation, you'll find this notation used this way in the context of [Lie theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#The_exponential_map) and [functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup). The general Lie-theoretic result is that given a continuous homomorphism $f:\mathbb R\to G$ from the additive group of real numbers to some matrix Lie group $G$, there must be some $X\in\mathrm{End}(G)$ such that $f(t)=\exp(tX)$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$. This $X$ would be the "generator" of the homomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\rho=\mathcal{L}\rho\qquad \Leftrightarrow\qquad \rho(t)=\exp(t\mathcal{L})\rho(0).
$$ In that sense, the Lindbladian $\mathcal{L}$ generates evolution through
$$\rho(dt)\approx \rho(0)+dt \mathcal{L}\rho(0),$$ which is the same sense as an infinitesmal generator of a Lie group. You might be familiar with something like a rotation of a vector $\mathbf{u}(0)$ by some rotation angle $|\mathbf{r}|$ about some axis pointing in the direction $\mathbf{r}$:
$$R(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{u}(s)=\exp(i  \mathbf{J}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathbf{u} (0)\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \mathbf{u}(d\mathbf{r})\approx \mathbf{u}(d\mathbf{r})+i \left(\mathbf{J}\cdot d\mathbf{r}\right) \,\mathbf{u}(0);$$ then, the operators $\mathbf{J}=(J_1,J_2,J_3)$ are the generators of rotations.

The idea is explicitly explained in Lindblad's [original paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-48/issue-2/On-the-generators-of-quantum-dynamical-semigroups/cmp/1103899849.full), from which the name ``generators of quantum dynamical semigroups'' derives, where the relevant fact is that $\lim_{t\to 0}\rho(t)=\rho(0)$.